# How to export state variable of react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

How to export state variable of `react.js`? means we have a state variable in `react.js` and this state variable needs to be in another component then how to we export that component.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: it acts as a similar way when you send paramters in a function in c/c++ etc

Comment: always try to go on the official site of the technology which you are studying or working with. that has most of it

Answer (score 1):

Just declare your `state`, import the `Component` which you want to send the state variable and then pass it as **attribute/parameter**.
Something is this:

```
import Data from './data';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
class Test extends Component {
    this.state = {
                firstName: "",
                lastName: "",
                dateOfBirth: "",
                emailAddress: "",
                fatherFirstName: "",
                fatherLastName: ""
            }

    componentDidMount() {
            this.props.setValues();
        }

    setValues= async () => {
            this.setState({
                firstName: "Teddy",
                lastName: "Bear",
                dateOfBirth: 2000-12-07,
                emailAddress: "teddybear@gmail.com",
                fatherFirstName: "Jonhathan",
                fatherLastName: "Bear"
            })
        }
render(){
return(
     <Container>
         <Data
             data={this.state}
         />
     </Container>
    )
   }

}
export default Test;
```

This is how it is done; how state variables are sent from one component to another component. You just need to send it as a parameter in a function. And this `data` sent in `Data` is used as `this.props`.

https://reactjs.org/ this site all you can start with and you can refer to this whenevr possible. I hope this simple interpretation will atleast tell you how it is done